# Why do we use equal sign?

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In these two lines, the author has used the equal sign inside the parenthesis.

```
self.vel_pub = rospy.Publisher(name=self.cmd_vel_topic, data_class=Twist, queue_size=10)
```

and

```
self.front_topic_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(name=self.front_sensor_topic, data_class=Range, callback=self.front_callback)
```

for example: name=self.cmd_vel_topic

Why did he do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403694/why-do-we-use-equal-sign?/) by [RoboTBiLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/77403/robotbill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The author is telling the function (in this case the constructor for the `rospy subscriber` class) which particular arguments the value they are passing in is for. If you look at the documentation for the subscriber class you will notice the `__init__()` function has `name`,`data_class`, and `callback` as arguments in the function definition. You don't necessarily have to do that, but then you need to be careful about the order you pass in the values to the function. Basically, the authors are explicitly telling the function which argument each value they pass in relates to.

Docs: [Subscriber](http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html)

---

Originally posted by [Stkr22](https://answers.ros.org/users/109047/stkr22/) with karma: 36 on 2022-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2